# Streaming MP4 video through RTSP

Tags: video, rtsp

I have RTSP server, programmed by myself. There are MP4 video file. Client of an RTSP server is VLC Media Player. That's messages between media player and server:

```
OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.1.6:5554/camera RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.2.4 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2016.02.22)

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
Session: 698955009;timeout=60
Expires: 0
Server: RTSP Camera Server (Android) ver. 1.8
Public: DESCRIBE,SETUP,TEARDOWN,PLAY,PAUSE,GET_PARAMETER,SET_PARAMETER
Cache-Control: no-cache

DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.1.6:5554/camera RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 3
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.2.4 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2016.02.22)
Accept: application/sdp

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Base: rtsp://192.168.1.6:5554/camera
Content-Length: 269
Session: 698955009;timeout=60
Expires: 0
Content-Type: application/sdp
Server: RTSP Camera Server (Android) ver. 1.8
Cache-Control: no-cache

v=2
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 192.168.1.6
s=RTSP_CAMERA
i=jpeg
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.6
t=0 0
a=recvonly
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 26
a=rtpmap:26 JPEG/90000
a=control:trackID=0
a=fmtp:26 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=640029;sprop-parameter-sets=Z2QAKawbGsBQBbk=,aOpDyw==;

SETUP rtsp://192.168.1.6:5554/camera/trackID=0 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 4
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.2.4 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2016.02.22)
Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;interleaved=0-1

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;ssrc=1337;interleaved=0-1;mode=play
Session: 698955009;timeout=60
Server: RTSP Camera Server (Android) ver. 1.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: 0

PLAY rtsp://192.168.1.6:5554/camera RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 5
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.2.4 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2016.02.22)
Session: 698955009
Range: npt=0.000-

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
Session: 698955009;timeout=60
Server: RTSP Camera Server (Android) ver. 1.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

Content description is invalid in my case. There are MJPEG is described instead of video.

**First question.** How to create correct description of media stream (`DESCRIBE` response)? Is there any valid tutorials?

**Second question.** How to correctly encode video frames and headers? I fount tutorial [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2435), but there is problem. That's my code of submit video:

```
// creating header
int Version = 2, Padding = 0, Extension = 0, Csrc = 0, Marker = 1, Ssrc = 0, SequenceNumber = 0, TimeStamp = 90000, PayloadType = 96;
SequenceNumber++;
header[0] = (byte) (Version << 6 | Padding << 5 | Extension << 4 | Csrc);
header[1] = (byte) (Marker << 7 | PayloadType);
header[2] = (byte) (SequenceNumber >> 8);
header[3] = (byte) (SequenceNumber & 255);
header[4] = (byte) (TimeStamp >> 24);
header[5] = (byte) (TimeStamp >> 16 & 255);
header[6] = (byte) (TimeStamp >> 8 & 255);
header[7] = (byte) (TimeStamp & 255);
header[8] = (byte) (Ssrc >> 24);
header[9] = (byte) (Ssrc >> 16 & 255);
header[10] = (byte) (Ssrc >> 8 & 255);
header[11] = (byte) (Ssrc & 255);
out.write(header); // send header
out.flush();
...
out.write(...); // send video
out.flush();
```

Nothing plays back client side. VLC don't showing me any errors, it's just stops loading video by closing the socket.

Main problem is I don't know how to broadcast MP4 video through RTSP.

---

It would not be worst if it's impossible. I can eject all JPEG pictures from the video to MJPEG file and separately raw audio. Maybe it would be better use UDP protocol with 2 streams: MJPEG video + raw audio. Tell me good solutions please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to stream MP4 video file through RTSP protocol?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654864/is-it-possible-to-stream-mp4-video-file-through-rtsp-protocol)

Comment: Look at the duplicate to find the response about MP4 over RTSP and my suggestion would be to simply use FFmpeg.

Comment: @RudolfsBundlis, that's not a dublicate. I don't understand their solution. I can't follow RFC instructions, you can see why above. I don't use FFmpeg and other licensed libraries. Or I use it if there are only one way unfortunately..

Comment: Well, you are asking if you can stream MP4 over RTSP - the linked question correctly answers no and gives a detailed explanation why (for another similar answer see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097042/does-rtsp-support-streaming-file-video-mp4). As for streaming JPEG over RTP there is a proper RFC - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2435